# this.getClass().getResource() not working uniformly

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

```
URL propFile = this.getClass().getResource("/sample.xml");
```

I am loading a properties file using  above method. And trying to do operations on it in a web application project. my sample.xml is there in my war file src.main.resources folder.

```
public void saveProperties(Properties prop) {
    log.info("URL is ::::::::::::::::::::" + propFile);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
    Path workflowPath = fs.getPath(propFile.getPath());
    try {
        OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(workflowPath);
        prop.storeToXML(os, "modified the path");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Properties getAllProperties() {
    Properties pro = new Properties();
    try {
        pro.loadFromXML(propFile.openStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pro;
}
```

I have above two methods. Not sure why `saveProperties` throws `FileNotFoundException` and `getAllProperties` is loading all properties from same file.

Exception stack trace

```
17:40:43,288 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /content/bwFLA.ear/workflows.war/WEB-INF/classes/sample.xml
17:40:43,288 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
17:40:43,289 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
17:40:43,289 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
17:40:43,290 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
17:40:43,290 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
17:40:43,290 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
17:40:43,291 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at de.bwl.bwfla.workflows.beans.common.PropertiesUtil.saveProperties(PropertiesUtil.java:35)
17:40:43,291 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at de.bwl.bwfla.workflows.beans.conf.WF_CONF_0.navigate(WF_CONF_0.java:44)
17:40:43,291 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at de.bwl.bwfla.workflows.beans.conf.WF_CONF_0$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.navigate(WF_CONF_0$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
17:40:43,292 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:40:43,292 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
17:40:43,293 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:40:43,293 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
17:40:43,294 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
17:40:43,294 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5)   at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278
```

Comment: Full stack trace would be helpful -- at least the line in `saveProperties` where the error is being thrown.

Comment: check what workflowPath contains, that will give you an idea why is this happening. Provide StackTrace for better help

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why are you attempting to save the file to the deploy space..? Do you very well realize that all changes in deploy space are completely lost when you redeploy the WAR?

Comment: @BalusC It is research project and specific to developers. This helps in connecting different systems on-fly.

Comment: Are you deploying an exploded war or a single file?

Comment: Also, you probably get better answers if you elaborate more on the "connecting systems" part instead of your attempted solution (which, as you noticed, is a hack at best).

Comment: modified the requirements to access file outside the war. this problem doesn't exist. Thanks everyone for valuable inputs.